# checking Caratheodory Measurability

Tags: measure-theory

> I had to show that,  if  $\mu(A)=0$, then 
>   $$\mu^∗(E) ≥ \mu^∗(E ∩ A) + \mu^*(E ∩ A^c)$$
>   where $\mu$ denotes the outer measure.

So it looks simple but Im already absolutely not sure what Im doing.
Can I use $\mu(E ∩ A^c)=\mu(E)-\mu(A)=\mu(E)$ and so on?
or may exists any better way?

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu (A)=0$ then $0\leq \mu^{*}(E\cap A)\leq \mu^{*}(A)=0$ so $\mu^{*}(E\cap A)=0$. Also  $\mu^{*}(E\cap A^{c})\leq \mu^{*}(E)$. Hence $\mu^{*}(E\cap A)+\mu^{*}(E\cap A^{c}) \leq \mu^{*}(E)$.

Comment: why µ(E∩ A)≤µ(A)?

Comment: @SELFIE Every outer measure has monotonicity property: $A \subset B$ implies $\mu (A) \leq \mu (B) $.

Comment: i know; but why is here E∩A⊂A?

Comment: @SELFIE If $x \in E\cap A$ then $x \in E$ **and** $x \in A$. In  particular $x \in A$.

Comment: ok i think i understand,thanx!